# Are the laws of mathematics 'absolute' in this universe?

Tags: logic, philosophy

We observe that almost all physical phenomena (which has been explained) can eventually be explained by the laws of mathematics. Mathematics seems ubiquitous- for example the form of the differential equation that governs the simple harmonic motion of a helical spring has the exact same form to explain the current in a RLC circuit. The parallels are endless virtually.
But it does not mean necessarily that the 'next to be discovered phenomenon' has to follow the laws of mathematics provided that there is a theorem out there which proves that every physical mechanism has to abide by the laws of maths.

Could anyone answer with a philosophical insight on this matter and has the Godel's Incompleteness theorem anything to say on this?

Comment: You must also admit the possibility that math arose from the attempt to explain the universe. (Yes, I know there are arguments on both sides.)

Comment: I'm not an expert in math or physics, but in my opinion, it's not correct to say "physics can eventually be explained by mathematics". The fact is that  _some_ part of mathematics happens to be the right _language_ to describe physical phenomena. Mathematics is interesting in its own light, but for physicists, it's only a convenient language(or tools) and nothing more.

Comment: i can see how you can math to *describe* physical phenomena, and also how, using those mathematical descriptions, you can providde further explanations and prdictions, but I don't see how all of physics follows from math. How does math, for example, imply that the gravitational constant has the value that it does .. or maybe even more basic ... that there is such a thing like gravity at all?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus It is true of what you are saying on how mathematics arose- but then look at the fact that it was discovered and not invented (some techniques of mathematics may have been invented though).

Comment: Why do you think math was discovered ? And you also have to explain the difference between discovery and invention. Did Edison discover or invent the light bulb ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus: You must admit the possibility that maths arose (e.g. Ancient Egypt) because of the desire of those in power to raise taxes and pay for large tombs.

Comment: @Bram28 Good perspective, let me try and suggest an example: physics as we knew and intuited exists never does actually existed- we discovered the quantum behavior of our universe at very small scales which (before actually conducting experiments) was theorized my rigorous mathematics almost all of which was abstract- yet this provides the most accurate description of reality which is absolutely beyond normal intuition. It manifestly does appear that the laws of mathematics were followed word by word even though our classical physics failed at that point.

Comment: @JamesArathoon What is this Social Justice garbage ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Of course though admittedly some techniques may have been 'designed' to make ends meet in solving a mathematical problem- but my inquiries go much deeper than that. There is this proposition- mathematics was there all along- it was only discovered as humans progressed in their intellectual pursuit. I only ask if this pursuit will eventually find that mathematics is destined to dictate everything in this universe that we will find (as it has shown to dictate till now).

Comment: I think it is a feedback loop. We use the ideas and technology available to us to describe the universe. And in turn the effectiveness of this description influences which ideas survive. For example we used to think the brain was a book, now we think its a computer. Both are probably wrong. But we could abandon the book model so easily because it didnt really explain anything. QFT is probably not in its final form, but you cant dismiss it cause it gives accurate predictions.

Comment: Yeah so I think there are new math discoveries (or inventions) in QFT. Well, this is also a millennium problem. One of the reasons to think this is cause it works as a physical theory.

Comment: The last sentence is just cringe worthy.

Answer (score 4):

If you haven't already read Eugene Wigner's essay "On the unreasonable effectiveness of mathematics in the natural sciences". It addresses most of what you mentioned.

https://www.dartmouth.edu/~matc/MathDrama/reading/Wigner.html

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be based on an assumption that the laws of mathematics are out there and the physicists are busy trying to apply them to understand the laws of physical reality, but actually the relation is often the opposite: certain physical phenomena often lead physicists to develop new mathematics that the mathematicians themselves may have been powerless to develop, lacking the necessary physical intuitions.  A spectacular example of this was the development of [Seiberg-Witten theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seiberg%E2%80%93Witten_invariant) that was used to almost "trivialize" previously spectacular (and complicated) mathematical develoments; see [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.6271) for a more detailed account.

Answer (score -2):

I think they are not.  Consider, for any consistent first-order theory S in any language L, the set S* of consistent theories of greater provability strength.  The incompleteness theorems tell us that if S is incomplete, then S* can be arranged in an upside-down pyramid, where each S' in S* can be extended with at least con(S') and not con(S'), giving an upwards branching structure of incompatible extensions.

If mathematics was absolute, then there would be a subset T(L) of first-order theories in S* that is the "true" tower without branching structure that traces out this absolute mathematical reality for the language L.

Is there such an absolute mathematical reality for any meaningful language L?  I don't think we have a universally accepted methodology for getting T(L) for arithmetic or set theory.

Comment: You might want to ask Jason if he knows what a first-order theory is :-)

Comment: @MikhailKatz I guess the first sentence and last paragraph are now more-or-less comprehensible to people who are not familiar with FOL.